# CMS which publishes flat file to remote web server

Tags: content-management-system

Is there a CMS I can run on my MacBook, which can publish flat files to the remote host web servers?

I am going to look after a couple of community sites on a volunteer basis - these exists in various different web hosts. The price of hosted CWM, e.g. WordPress, is beyond my budget for each of these web sites.

What I am hoping is that I can run a CMS on my Mac, or Windows, and push flat HTML files of the various websites, to the remote web servers.

Based on research the closest to meeting the requirements is http://www.fogcreek.com/citydesk/; unfortunately this is no longer supported product - would anyone have alternate solution?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/143302)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not actually an CMS, but you could try [Markdoc](http://markdoc.org/).